# PHP send email from html message

Tags: php, html, email

I've created a simple php email script but the problem is that I dont want to include the large message text in the same php file. I want the script to read the message (exactly as it appears, with html code) from a separate html file. I've tried to replace the message with `include("body.html");` but that unfortunately prints the html code rather than send it.

This is a small version of my script

```
<?php
    $to .= 'email@example.com';
    $subject = 'Message Subject';
    $message = 'This is a very important message?';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: Person Name <pname@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` reads the contents of a file into a string.  So you could do something like this:

```
$message = file_get_contents('./message_file.html');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for more information.

Especially if the contents of the file might be user generated, this has the advantage of there being no chance that any part of the file will be parsed as PHP and executed on your server.  (There are still all the important security issues to worry about in delivering HTML to end users when you aren't the source of the content.)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a body.php file with contents of your message stored in a variable, for example:

```
$message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed nec dui vitae augue elementum facilisis sit amet in est. Vestibulum lacinia, magna a dictum pretium, mi enim pharetra ligula, at aliquet arcu leo quis libero. Ut ornare dapibus pulvinar. Cras vel nisl nibh. Quisque semper porta augue, in adipiscing elit ultricies eu. Mauris laoreet leo ut justo luctus ut ullamcorper urna feugiat. Vestibulum a massa mauris, sit amet aliquam lorem. Nullam malesuada, neque vel imperdiet aliquet, nisl neque luctus tortor, sed dapibus tellus elit non est. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Mauris vulputate convallis lorem et scelerisque.";
```

And then `include("body.php");` somewhere above the `mail()` call.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a file `body.php` and have it contain something like this:

```
$message = 'formatted, escaped and ready message goes here';
```

And include that.

Comment: Thanks but I'll use Trott's method :)